# Bazel emits wrong hostname to stabe-status.txt

Tags: macos, bazel

I'm building on Mac. Bazel emits workspace status to the file `bazel-out/stabe-status.txt` where he writes the hostname.

I changed all my hostnames as described [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fapple.stackexchange.com%2Fa%2F287775&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHh_orsviFMV2t9awO4SpZoSybUiQ), but bazel keeps emitting the old hostname.

Why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4940).

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks! Looks very similar, but if there is no dependency on this file, why it's recreated by bazel?